# Fill NA in PySpark DataFrame by group with values from Pandas lookup table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with missing values in `col2` that I would like to impute, based on values in `col1`. For example:

```
df
id    col1    col2
0      A       1
1      A      NA
2      B       2
3      B      NA
4      B       3
```

I would like to impute these missing values using a given Pandas lookup table:

```
pdf_lookup
id    col1    col2
0      A       4
1      B       5
```

So the desired result would be the following PySpark DataFrame:

```
id    col1    col2
0      A       1
1      A       4
2      B       2
3      B       5
4      B       3
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this? A scalable solution would be ideal since `df` may be very large with up to hundreds of columns (i.e. `col3`, ..., `col500`) that need to be imputed based on `col1`. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a join then a coalesce to keep only the non-null values of 2 columns:

```
pdf_lookup = pdf_lookup.select(col("col1"), col("col2").alias("col2_tmp"))
df.join(pdf_lookup, ["col1"], "left").withColumn("col2", coalesce(col("col2"), col("col2_tmp"))).drop("col2_tmp").show()
```